# PHP add value to a existing query string

Tags: php, query-string, duplicates

Here is the problem:

I have a page that is all based on query strings, something like:

```
localhost\sandbox\hotsite.php?id=14665&open=hot_promocoes&titulo=127121
```

And i'm developing a pagination function to this CMS, so i want to do something that do this for me:

```
localhost\sandbox\hotsite.php?id=14665&open=hot_promocoes&titulo=127121&pg=1
```

Right now, i've created a code that takes the entire URL and add the pg=1, but when I do this and click on some new page link for example page 3, the link looks like this:

```
localhost\sandbox\hotsite.php?id=14665&open=hot_promocoes&titulo=127121&pg=1&pg=3.
```

And it repeats forever(`titulo=127121&pg=1&pg=3&pg=2&pg=4&pg=8&pg=9&pg=2&pg=3`) as i click the pages links, and when it happens my pagination code goes crazy, if i continues to click my code just go nuts. I'm stuck at this, I just can't figure a way out of it.

A additional info: Each page has a differente structure so

- if the content is photos the link looks like this:

  localhost\sandbox\hotsite.php?id=14665&open=hot_albums&titulo=127991
- if the content is videos the link looks like this:

  localhost\sandbox\hotsite.php?id=14665&open=videos&album=1348&titulo=11121

So i just cant build anything using the build string function from php, cause the only query string value that i know for sure is the id one, that will be on all the pages but the other ones are not constant.

So, i need your help :).

```
        // START OF FUNCTION
        function stringadd($query_text) {

            $query = $query_text;

                $pound = "";
                $poundPos = -1;

                    //Is there a #?
                    if ( ( $poundPos = strpos( $url_atual, "#" ) ) !== false )
                        {
                            $pound = substr( $url_atual, $poundPos );
                            $url_atual = substr( $url_atual, 0, $poundPos );
                        }

                $separator = (parse_url($url_atual, PHP_URL_QUERY) == NULL) ? '?' : '&';
                $url_atual .= $separator . $query . $pound;

          echo "".$url_atual;
        }
      // here is what i do to execute the function:



<?php echo stringadd('pg=').$total_paginas ;?>
```

Comment: before you move on, you have to understand that URL uses slash instead of backslash. Also, you didn't post your codes.

Comment: _I know this is old but for legacy purposes;_ Simply use: `echo http_build_url($url_atual, array("query" => "pg=".$total_paginas), HTTP_URL_JOIN_QUERY);`. But you'll need `pecl install pecl_http` or install [jakeasmith/http_build_url](https://github.com/jakeasmith/http_build_url) via composer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`parse_str`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) function will give you an array of key-value pairs from your query string value.  Working on an array will make things cleaner as existing keys will inherently be overridden instead of appended.

```php
function setQueryString($url, $key, $val){
    $pUrl = parse_url($url);
    if(isset($pUrl['query']))
        parse_str($pUrl['query'], $pUrl['query']);
    else $pUrl['query'] = [];
    $pUrl['query'][$key] = $val;

    $scheme = isset($pUrl['scheme']) ? $pUrl['scheme'].'://' : '';
    $host = isset($pUrl['host']) ? $pUrl['host'] : '';
    $path = isset($pUrl['path']) ? $pUrl['path'] : '';
    $path = count($pUrl['query'])>0 ? $path.'?' : $path;

    return $scheme . $host . $path . http_build_query($pUrl['query']);
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://ideone.com/NDADgP)

Comment: _I know this is old but for legacy purposes;_ Simply use: `echo http_build_url($url, array("query" => $key."=".$val), HTTP_URL_JOIN_QUERY);`. But you'll need `pecl install pecl_http` or install [jakeasmith/http_build_url](https://github.com/jakeasmith/http_build_url) via composer.